# how to clear individual pixels?

Tags: cocos2d-x, opengl-es-2.0

how to clear individual pixels in a raw data(unsigned char*)?

the data is from render texture by this method:

```
unsigned char* data = rt->newImage();
```

is there anyway i can do that (clear/erase) individual pixels in a raw data ... maybe i can apply some blending mode on it with OpenGL or something ... but how could i do that while operating on a raw data.

anyway i just want to clear some pixels using any approach available.

the raw data is rgba8888 (32 bit).

Comment: and what is the difficulty? You have everything to compute you pixel pointer (rgba8888), you may set char[ptrPix] to your clear value.

Comment: can you explain in code please.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/

Comment: i dont think you understand me quite well... what i want is a way to clear individual pixels at a specific location not some pointer tutorial i can handle pointers just fine.

Comment: ambiguous, "individual pixels at a specific location" a frame buffer or a texture or where?

Comment: unsigned char pixel = data[(y * w + x) * 4];// i've got the x and y coordinates from the raw image data

so what i want is to delete that pixel at that x and y position

Comment: So your problem is to understand what `clear` or `delete` stands for, right?

Comment: don't get confused by the word delete i used earlier what i just meant is to replace the pixel color with a transparent one which is the same as clearing it ...i don't actually mean to delete it.

Comment: what is the problem with a statement for clearing like: `for(i=0;i<4;i++)` `data[(y * stride + x ) * 4 + i] = 0;`

Comment: i tried it like this :

int index = (x + (h - y - 1) * w) * 4;
data[index] = 0;
data[index + 1] = 0;
data[index + 2] = 0;
data[index + 3] = 0;

and it worked too.

Comment: be aware that opengl has a default Y flip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
bool CreatorScene::setPixel(int x, int y, int r, int g, int b, int a, unsigned char* data){
        if(x < 0 || x >= canvasWidth || y < 0 || y >= canvasHeight) return false;
        int index = (x + (canvasHeight - y - 1) * canvasWidth) * 4;

        data[index] = r;
        data[index + 1] = g;
        data[index + 2] = b;
        data[index + 3] = a;

        return true;
}
```

you can also disable coords checking to increase performance.

For bigger area you can use memset. But pixels must be neighbours.

Comment: i also tried this and it worked:

int i = (x + (h - y - 1) * w) * 4 + 3; 

data[i] = 0;

Comment: i also noticed that there is some slight offset happens when using this formula:
int i = (x + (h - y - 1) * w) * 4;
which i really couldn't figure out?

Comment: canvas bounds are (0, 0)->(canvasWidth - 1, canvasHeight - 1). And also bitmap in memory is from top to bottom, while opengl is from bottom to top (y axis). That's why you have to invert y and substract 1.

Comment: so what do you suggest in order to resolve the offsetting problem?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot how it looks? This method is working fine, I'm using it in countless projects.. Also using this method I have more advanced methods so I'm using I'd see some problems if I'd be wrong..